# Firebase cloud functions for multiple projects at the same app flavor

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In my app I'm working with multiple Firebase projects because I need my DB to be logically separated by countries.

For that, I'm using FirebaseOptions to access databases from different Firebase projects at runtime.

In addition, on each Firebase project I have the same cloud function, deployed respectively.

The problem is that **only** the cloud function of the default Firebase project (the one declared in the google-services.json file) is working. It seems that FirebaseOptions doesn't influence the execution of cloud functions.

Anyone has a clue?

- It is important to note that I don't have different flavors per country in my app.

**Solution**

I could only send notification to registration tokens that were associated for a particular sender ID. Basically, I was trying to send to tokens that belonged to other project.

To do this, I should have allowed multiple projects to send messages to the same client app. To enable this feature, we need to make sure we have each project's sender ID. When requesting registration, the client app fetches the token multiple times, each time with a different sender ID in audience field, using the token retrieval method.

In other terms, we'll have to call getToken() passing the sender ID and simply "FCM" (e.g. getToken("2xxxxx3344", "FCM")) as the parameters. Also make sure that you call this for each sender (project) that you need.

Comment: What type of cloud function are you using (trigger, HTTP function, something else)?  Can you describe what you mean by "only the cloud function of the default Firebase project (the one declared in the google-services.json file) is working"?  How do you know that only one function is working - what unexpected behavior are you seeing?

Comment: Trigger. When onCreate() is getting called it then constructs a notification and sends it to the receiver's token. The unexpected behavior is that FirebaseMessagingService is being fired, but NOT always. **Despite I declare a FirebaseOptions** for the relevant country project (determined in run time), the FirebaseMessagingService is being fired only for the project properties declared in the google-services.json file. For that matter, when I make an attempt and replace the google-services.json with the file of another project (say X), the FirebaseMessagingService is being fired **just for** X.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what your setup is like.  Please edit your question to include what code you have on both the Android client and Cloud Functions backend, and how you expect those bits of code to be executed in a specific situation.

Comment: Based on what you are saying, it appears that the cloud functions are working correctly but your app is not able to receive messages from more than one Firebase project at once.  So, your question is really "How do I configure an Android app to receive FCM messages from multiple Firebase projects".  Are you subscribing to FCM topics and expecting to receive messages, or are your cloud functions sending messages targeted to one device using the instance ID?

Comment: They are targeted to specific devices using instance IDs.

Comment: I'm really not even sure if it is possible to accomplish what you want, but here are a few more thoughts.  On each device, the app will have different instance IDs for each Firebase project.  Are you registering all of those instance IDs with the server from the app?  Is the server sending messages to the right instance ID for the app on your device?  Also, as requested earlier, "Please edit your question to include what code you have on both the Android client and Cloud Functions backend, and how you expect those bits of code to be executed in a specific situation".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem in your build variants.

If im right. You can use env-variables and >firebase use (cli command) to controll your builds.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#env-variables

Initilize FireBase-Admin-SDK.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

A first Idea of how to import different cred.json files.

```
import serviceAccountProd = require("./prodCred.json");
import serviceAccountDev = require("./devCred.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(
  development ? (serviceAccountDev as admin.ServiceAccount) : (serviceAccountProd as admin.ServiceAccount)),
  databaseURL: database,
  storageBucket: bucket,
});
```

i didnt implemented it fully - feel free to edit